# Mongoose: How to correctly update nested documents

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am attempting to update a specific value within a nested document. Assume that the key value pair will already exist:

Schema:

```
Child = mongoose.Schema({
     key1  :  String,
     key2  :  String,


Parent = mongoose.Schema({
  sample:{
     key1  :  String,
     key2  :  [Child],
```

The parent document may contain multiple nested documents with 'parent.key2', assume i know the specific _id value of the nested document. I have tried multiple variations of .save / .update / .findby.... with zero success.

i am now at the folowing point:

```
sample.update(
  {_id : 'Known-ID-of-Nested-Document'},
  {$set : {key1 : value}},
  {upsert: true},

  function(err){...}
```

The above does not work - what am i doing wrong?

EDIT: i used 'findOneAndUpdate' method like so:

```
var query   = {<dataPath>._id    : 'Known-ID-of-Nested-Document'}
var update  = {<dataPath>.$.Key1 : 'newValue'}
var options = {upsert = true}

sample.findOneAndUpdate(query, update, options).......
```

i had initially failed with this approach because my update variable was looking like this:

```
var query = {key1: 'newValue'}
```

Turns out i needed the path and $ to find the nested document eg:

```
parent.child.$.<key-to-amend>
```

Hope this may help someone along the way.

Comment: What's `sample` that you're calling `update` on?

Comment: sample would be something like : =mongoose.model('dbname', Parent)

Comment: Fixed, see Edit for details